# How to access "previous sibling" of `this` when iterating over a selection?

Tags: d3.js

In the following code, assume that `$sel` is some *arbitrary* d3.js selection:

```
$sel.each(function(d, i, j) {
              var prev = ??? ;
              ...
          });
```

What can I replace the `???` to assign to `prev` a d3.js selection consisting of *the previous sibling of `this`* (if any such exists)?

(If `this` is a first child, and therefore has no previous sibling, an empty d3.js selection should be assigned to `prev`.)

Comment: In general, you can't do that, because there's no selector for the previous sibling of something. It sounds like you'd be better off operating off the parent element though and selecting children as required.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It might be as simple as

```
var prev = d3.select(this.previousSibling);
```

If you are interested in element nodes only you would go for

```
var prev = d3.select(this.previousElementSibling);
```

```js
d3.selectAll(".c").each(function() {
    console.log(d3.select(this));                         // Element <p class="c"></p>
    console.log(d3.select(this.previousSibling));         // text node containing whitespace between b and c
    console.log(d3.select(this.previousElementSibling));  // Element <p class="b"></p>
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p class="a"></p>
    <p class="b"></p>
    <p class="c"></p>
    <p class="d"></p>
    <p class="e"></p>
</div>
```